# How do I backup a failing disk?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, disk, fsck

I'm trying to recover some information on a failing disk. At this point, it won't let me log in(asks for a manual fsck run which gets stuck during runtime). I'm guessing I can access some of the files using a recovery disk. How do I proceed from there on?

Comment: Mount the disk to a running OS. Sometimes the only option may be a live USB with separate USB media to transfer files to. Plan on no more than one more successful boot before you are sending off to the recovery service.

Comment: @Paul So how exactly do I transfer the files? Let's say I've booted into a live USB. How would I recover the files given that I have external storage.

Comment: There is no sure way to backup a falty HDD. Try to mount as 'read only' and see if it is possible to copy anything. Use `ddrescue`.

Comment: As already stated, there is no sure way to get data off a failing disk.  I'd for sure not try and run it (ie. do **not** try and boot it), do all exploration from *live* media, and firstly validate the health using SMART (it uses the electronics on the drive for data, so won't impact remaining life; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) then I'd copy what matters most to other media; then use tools to try & get it all... but concentrate on most-critical data first.  Recovery is not fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoudl try to clone the disk using *ddrescue* as described [here](https://www.cgsecurity.org/testdisk.pdf)
Once it's done, remove the original disk and run *TestDisk*, *Advanced*, *Boot*, *RebuildBS*, *List*.
If you can see your files, choose *Write*, confirm, *Quit* and restart your computer.